# Why are "not greater/less" (e.g. "!>" or "!<") operators not used in most programming languages

Tags: syntax, comparison, operators, programming-languages

I understand that you can get the same behavior by using `<=` or `!(x > y)` but I usually rather think in terms of **not greater** instead of **less than or equal**, so having something like `!>` and `!<` would actually be really neat to have for me and would match the `!=` operator perfectly.

The `!(x > y)` syntax requires more characters and reads: **not: x is greater than y**, which is unhandy and very unlike natural speech.

I have never seen `!<` or `!>` operators anywhere, but have been wondering ever since I started programming why they are not supported. Are there any reasons why not?

Comment: !> is same as <= and !< is same as >= no one has tought that they'd need x !> y instead of !(x > y) or x <= y

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that it`s a nice pinch of syntactic sugar? I would like to see these operators become widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Using the least number of logical and comparison operators, and those the most closest to classic math and logic makes it simpler to reason about conditions.

There were programming languages like Natural and COBOL with operators like **NOT LESS THAN**, but reasoning about `(a !< b)` when thinking over a complex condition is much more difficult than `!(a < b)`, which is equivalent to `(a >= b)`.

An example:

```
!(!(a < b) && !(a > c))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
!((a >= b) && (a <= c))
```

which translates to:

```
(a < b) || (a > c)
```

There's nothing to gain from `!((a !< b) && (a !> c))`?

Comment: The example does not show a case where `!<` would be useful. It is really as simple as the difference between `!(a > b)` and `(a !< b)` or `(a >= b)`, which would all be equivalent, of course. The point I am making is simply that the current operators are less natural to read than `(a !< b)`; **"a not less than b"**. It may seem redundant, but I think languages should be ergonomic wherever possible. And I don`t understand the disadvantage of having multiple operators for the same behavior. It allows the programmer to adjust the code structure better and be more expressive.

Comment: That *not greater than* is easier to read than *less than or equal to* is (like many "easier to read" topics) an opinion, and not fact.  I happen to hold the opposite opinion.  FWIW, I have seen (but do not now recall) implementations of programming languages where the "less than or equal" operator was written ```!>```, which always struck me as a bizarre choice.  I believe PL/I had ```¬>``` (using the EBCDIC 'not` character) as well as ```<=```, but then PL/I always did want to have every possible option.

Comment: Of course, these operators should not replace the old ones, often *greater than or equals* makes perfect sense in the context. However I often found myself thinking something like: "if there are no more than 10 items in this list" but then having to type "if there are less than or exactly 10 items in this list" or "if -_not_- there are more than 10 items in this list"... I just don't see the harm in adding an operator that would read "if there are not more than 10 items in this list".

Comment: In all this analysis we are assuming a and b to be numerical. What if a=5 and b='w' ? in this case if we would like to do sth where `a !> b`, then `a <= b` would not capture it cuz a <= b would also be false in this case. Only !(a > b) would work.